# find interval from value

Tags: c++, find

Suppose I've a list of intervals: `[1, 90], [104, 234], [235, 300], ...`. Every interval has a name `A1, B, B1, ...`. Given a value I want the name of the interval (`112 -> B`, `100 -> special_value`). What's the best and faster implentation? Something better than a list of `if` / `else if`.

The intervals are sorted in order, and there is no overlap. I have a lot of values as input, but only one set of intervals. The size intervals are very different, some are very small, other are very large.

Comment: Are the intervals ordered? Have the intervals common parts?

Comment: What's the biggest value in your intervals?

Comment: @Xeo: now the biggest one is `170482`, but in future it will increase a lot. I think `unsigned int` will fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea: make a map object for the begin value of interval. If we found the possible interval, check if the value is in the interval.

```
class MyInterval
{
public:
  MyInterval( double begin, double end )
  : m_begin(begin), m_end(end)
  {
  };
  double m_begin, m_end;
};

bool operator < (  const MyInterval& left,  const MyInterval& right )
{
  return ( left.m_begin < right.m_begin );
}

std::map<MyInterval,std::string> store;
// use upper_bound to get the place+1 and then you could check the interval
std::map<MyInterval,std::string>::iterator iter = store.upper_bound( MyInterval(value,value) );
if ( iter != store.begin() )
{
  --iter;
  if ( iter->first.m_end >= value ) 
  {
    std::string result_text = iter->second;
    // Here is your result
  }
}
```

More info: [link](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/container/map/upper_bound).

It was tested in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: what if the value doesn't belong to any intervals?

Comment: are you sure? What from my example I use 100 as value?

Comment: and if there is an interval that matches then `iter->first` gives that interval, while `iter->second` gives the name of that interval

Comment: @wiso Do you want to be able to search for any value that lies within the bounds of the interval?

Comment: any values: -100, 100, 1000000. You forgot `const` to `operator<`

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. If the value is not found then you will indeed not get the results you expect. `lower_bound()` returns the first value which doesn't compare less than an element in the sorted container. You want to first look if the value is in the container, and then retrieve it. @Naszta, this answer is wrong.

Comment: @wiso: I don't understand why. I will check it today later. Theoretically the code seems to be good.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it looks like the intervals are sorted in order, and there is no overlap. There may be gaps, though.

Any sort of iteration will yield a O(N) solution - you can improve on it by doing a binary search of the intervals to where your value fits.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest improvement to a sequence of `else if`s is to create a linked list (or an array) of intervals and iterate over it. This seems like quite a simplistic piece of advice, so I hope it addresses your question.